# JPA batch update: do I have to flush() and clear() entity manager before last transaction commit()?

Tags: java, jpa, heap-memory, batch-processing, entitymanager

I am updating large number of rows in Oracle database. For that reason, I am doing batch update. My code seems to be working fine. I just realized that, I do not flush() or clear() entity manager before the last user transaction commit (also in case when number of managed entities is not divisible by batch size). Would it cause any issue? Recently I have been seeing out of memory errors on my server and I see lot of "org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl" objects in the heap memory. My entity manager is managed by the container. So I can not close it explicitly. I am wondering if there are any flaws with this batch update logic.

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class BackEndBean {
    ...
    ...

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "TEST_DB")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction tx;

    ...
    ...

    try {
        tx.begin();
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        //Criteria query with IN clause
        List<EntityClass> managedEntities   = typedQuery.getResultList();
        
        int batchSize = 200;
        for (int count = 0; count < managedEntities.size(); count++) {
            EntityClass entity = managedEntities.get(count);
            entity.setSomething("test");
            entity = entityManager.merge(entity);
            entityManager.persist(entity);
            if (count > 0 && count % batchSize == 0) {
                entityManager.flush();
                entityManager.clear();

                tx.commit();
                tx.begin();
            }
        }

        tx.commit();

    } catch (final Exception e) {
       
        if (tx != null) {
            try {
                tx.rollback();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // log error
            }
        }
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

JDK version is 1.7. Server is JBOSS EAP 6.4. I have read about setting following hibernate properties in persistence.xml, but it doesn't seem to be making any difference in my case. Hibernate version is 4.2 (bundled inside JBOSS):

- hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_size
- hibernate.query.in_clause_parameter_padding
- hibernate.query.plan_parameter_metadata_max_size
- hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_soft_references

Comment: You might have to issue a JoinTransaction https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#joinTransaction-- on the EntityManager when managing transactions yourself. Check the statements issued to be sure.

Comment: @Chris documentation says, joinTransaction should be called on application managed entity manager. My entity manager is manged by my container.

Comment: Are statements going to the database on all transaction commit calls if you remove the flush call? If not, your entity manager might not be joined to your user transactions, so might not receive the before/after commit callbacks. If it is working, you don't need to call anything - you don't even need to flush - just call clear after the transaction commit call(s)

Comment: @Chris Yes, the DB is getting updated without any issue. I call clear just before committing the transaction. I hope that's ok. I am wondering if I need to call clear again just before the final commit. Because when number of total managed entries OR number of remaining managed entries during loop, are less than the batch size, code inside if condition is not invoked (flush and clear are not invoked). So I m wondering, If I need to additionally invoke clear just before the last commit. I see lot of "org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl" in heap memory.

Comment: One thing why the `merge` and `persist`? The call to `merge` is already enough. You might want to set the `hibernate.order_inserts`, `hibernate.order_updates` and `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` to improve performance. You are also using multiple transactions, instead of 1 large transaction, I would remove the commit/start in between and do everything in 1 single large tx. Finally, you retrieve everything in 1 go (the `getResultList`) which can be a large result, why not stream it/iterate it (this would require casting the `Entitymanager` to a `Session` but reduces the memory usage).

Answer (score 0):

Clearing just removes references to managed entities, allowing them to be GC'd if the app isn't using them. This will happen when the EntityManager is closed, which the container will do on its own, so there should be no need to call clear at the end.